# Shell: How do I create a directory only if it does not exist?

Tags: shell

I have the following directory structure:

/home/aero/airplane/mach0p8

with in the mach0p8 directory I perform the following shell command:

```
mkdir ../convergence
```

If I repeat the same command I get the following message:

"mkdir cannot create directory '../convergence': File exists"

This obviously makes sense, however, I'm running a script and sometimes this file exists and sometimes it doesn't. I want to avoid the message statement above if possible. Anyone know what I could possibly do to overcome this? I would think there must be a shell command that would use some logic to determine if a file exists and if it did not it would then create it. I'm sure there is a simpler approach to this that I'm unaware of.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mkdir -p ../convergence
```

From man page:

> -p, --parents
>   no error if existing, make parent directories as needed

Answer (score 0):

You could do like others have answered.

```
mkdir -p ../convergence
```

Or you could check for it's existence and then make one.

```
[[ -d ../convergence ]] || mkdir ../convergence
```

First one is preferred.